# error vista preliminar de rdlc creado en VS2012 y lo abri en VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

tengo un reporte creado en VS2012 pero al abrirlo en VS2019 cuando quiero editar mi reporte solo me abre el XML y no la vista preliminar donde yo pueda agregar los objetos tablas, textbox etc a mi reporte asi es como me lo muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Supongo que te falta instalar los [SqlServer Data Tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: si eso era, los instale y ya pude ver el reporte rdlc correctamente